# Multiple Order By and Order by nearest value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to find the logic or method should i do to find nearest value

Storage data like this

| ID | Loc_id | item_id | batch | exp_date | qty | pick | put | pallet | location_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | M-16-10 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-16 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 1001 | PICK |
| 22 | M-16-10 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-16 | 52 | 0 | 0 | 1002 | PICK |
| 23 | K-15-60 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-17 | 42 | 0 | 0 | 1003 | RACK |
| 24 | K-17-50 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-18 | 32 | 0 | 0 | 1004 | RACK |
| 25 | K-20-60 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-19 | 33 | 0 | 0 | 1005 | RACK |
| 26 | K-24-60 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-20 | 42 | 0 | 0 | 1006 | RACK |
| 27 | K-26-40 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-21 | 22 | 0 | 0 | 1007 | RACK |
| 28 | K-27-20 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-22 | 32 | 0 | 0 | 1008 | RACK |
| 29 | K-32-40 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-23 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 1009 | RACK |

Order data like this

| id | outstanding | item_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 42 | 1 |

And code like this

```
$xsql = Storage::select('storages.*')
                    ->selectRaw("min(qty) as min_qty")
                    ->where('item_id', $outstanding->item_id)
                    ->whereRaw('(qty-pick) <= ?',[$outstanding->outstanding])
                    ->whereRaw('qty-pick>0')
                    ->orderBy('exp_date', 'asc')
                    ->orderByRaw('abs((qty-pick)-"'.$outstanding->outstanding.'")')
                    ->groupBy('id')
                    ->first();
```

The query if i dump

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    storages 
WHERE
    item_id = 1 
    AND qty - pick > 0 
    AND qty - pick <= 42 
GROUP BY
    id 
ORDER BY
    exp_date ASC,
    abs( ( qty - pick ) - 42 )
```

If I execute with this code, I get wrong result
Current result

| ID | Loc_id | item_id | batch | exp_date | qty | pick | put | pallet | location_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | K-15-60 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-17 | 42 | 0 | 0 | 1003 | RACK |

The first row that system show was Storage ID 23 not 21
(exp date storage id 21 is nearly exp than storage id 23),
how to combine order by exp_date asc and order by nearest value from the outstanding value?

my expected result was like this

| ID | Loc_id | item_id | batch | exp_date | qty | pick | put | pallet | location_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | M-16-10 | 1 | 092021 | 2024-08-16 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 1001 | PICK |

Comment: What is _pick_qty_? It is not a column in your _storages_ table.

Comment: sorry, i mean `pick`  @lukas.j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to use LIMIT:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM storages 
   WHERE item_id = 1 AND qty - pick BETWEEN 1 AND 42
ORDER BY exp_date ASC
   LIMIT 1
```

This would be a solution where the table with the outstanding value is joined:

```
  SELECT storages.* 
    FROM storages 
    JOIN outstanding USING (item_id)
   WHERE outstanding.item_id = 1 
     AND qty - pick BETWEEN 1 AND outstanding.outstanding
ORDER BY exp_date ASC
   LIMIT 1
```

And this would give you the result for all rows in *outstanding*:

```
   SELECT storages.* 
     FROM storages 
     JOIN outstanding USING (item_id)
    WHERE qty - pick BETWEEN 1 AND outstanding.outstanding
 GROUP BY outstanding.item_id
 ORDER BY exp_date ASC
```

See example [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb577b/11)

Comment: for example outstanding 52. 
in data storage qty is 8 and another 52 
i wanna see 52 before 8? its possible? thanks

Comment: Change the ORDER BY clause accordingly.

Comment: like this?
`SELECT storages.* 
    FROM storages 
    JOIN outstanding USING (item_id)
   WHERE outstanding.item_id = 1 
     AND qty - pick BETWEEN 1 AND outstanding.outstanding
ORDER BY exp_date ASC, abs( ( qty - pick ) - 52 ) 
   LIMIT 1`